# Binding ngFor with lazyloading inplace

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm geting the **Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.**  error.

But I couldn't get it resolved with the available answers. In general every answer say to import **BrowserModule** in the application's main module (app.module.ts) file and also import **CommonModule** in the child module.

I'm trying to use lazyloading and I wonder is this happening due to my componenet structure?

[image]

In `price.component.html` I get the below error when I use `*ngFor`

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let book of booksList">{{ book.author }}</li>
</ul>

Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.
```

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./landing/landing.module').then(m => m.LandingModule) },
  { path: 'books', loadChildren: () => import('./books/books.module').then(m => m.BooksModule) }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**books.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BooksRoutingModule } from './books-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BooksRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class BooksModule { }
```

**books-routing.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthorsComponent } from './authors/authors.component';
import { PriceComponent } from './price/price.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PriceComponent },
  { path: '/authors', component: AuthorsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), CommonModule],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [AuthorsComponent, PriceComponent]
})
export class BooksRoutingModule { }
```

### EDIT

price.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BookInfoService } from '../../book-info.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-price',
  templateUrl: './price.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./price.component.scss']
})
export class PriceComponent implements OnInit {

  booksList={};
  constructor( private httpBooks: BookInfoService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpBooks.getBookDetails().subscribe( (result) => {
      this.booksList = result;
      console.log('book list ---> ' + this.booksList);
    })
  }
}
```

consloe in price page

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), CommonModule],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [AuthorsComponent, PriceComponent] // <-- remove, not declaration here, not nice
})
export class BooksRoutingModule { }
```

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AuthorsComponent, PriceComponent], // <-- put here. :)
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BooksRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class BooksModule { }
```

You have **NOT** shared your PriceComponent with us... So..

```js
@Component(...)
export class PriceComponent {
    bookList = [];
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let book of booksList">{{ book.author }}</li>
</ul>
```

**Side node:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PriceComponent },
  { path: '/authors', component: AuthorsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AuthorsComponent, PriceComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BooksRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes) // <-- work
  ]
})
export class BooksModule { }
```

**Update 1:**

- Use: Resolve and your component will be inited by valid data. So Angular will first try resolve data and next step is component load with resolved data.

```js
// response model. (not required. If it not define set "Resolve<any>")
interface BookDetailsModel {
  id: number;
  book: string;
  author: string;
}; 

// https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve
@Injectable()
export class BookDetailsResolve implement Resolve<BookDetailsModel> {
  
  constructor(private httpBooks: BookInfoService ) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<BookDetailsModel> | Promise<BookDetailsModel> | BookDetailsModel {
    return this.httpBooks.getBookDetails(); // use error handler!
  }
}
```

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '/authors', component: AuthorsComponent},
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: PriceComponent, 
    resolve: { details: BookDetailsResolve } // <-- add resolver
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],

  // it is work, but I recommend add providers to normal module, just I dont want copy more code. :) 
  providers: [BookDetailsResolve]  // if not root provider, have to add to any parent or local module.
})
export class BooksRoutingModule { }
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-price',
  templateUrl: './price.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./price.component.scss']
})
export class PriceComponent implements OnInit {

  // typed attribute help your IDE. :)
  booksList: BookDetailsModel[] = []; // you can not foreach object! So I set to array.
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.booksList = this.route.snapshot.data.details; // resolve key name will data.KEY. It will normal type, not Observable.
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks Numichi. if I move it from the `books-routing.module` to the `books.module` what about the routes?

Comment: Nothing. Routing and component declaration are different topics. By default, you can define routing in standard module and not required routing module. Basically, routing module is separate from module and therefore more maintainable.

Comment: Added a "Side note" block in my answer. Ya! Not need CommonModule in RoutingModule too like declarations. :)

Comment: got it! +10 thanks. I'm trying things with your suggestion...couldn't fix it yet though

Comment: I hope, You are using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and not component name. :)

Comment: Yes.. the routing is fine. Please see my EDIT (right at the bottom). I've added a screnshot of the console (`price` page)

Comment: Check Update 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your component in the module file.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PriceComponent, AuthorsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BooksRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class BooksModule { }
```